# implement empirical cdf c++

Tags: c++, qt-creator, cdf

I want to define empirical cdf in C++ according to intervals fixed by N samples received and I should save the 2 vectors (T and Y)!
I made this code but it didn't work:

```
double cum_dist_funct::real_cdf_function(vec X,double x,int N,int Ndft,vec &T, vec &Z)
{
    Z.set_size(X.length());
    Z.zeros();
    vec V;
    V.set_size(N);
    V.zeros();
    double f0=0;
    T.set_size(X.length());
    T.zeros();
    T=X;
    for (int i=0; i<Ndft;i++)
    {
        V=X.get(i*N,(i+1)*N-1);
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            if(x<V[0]) f0=0;
            else if (V[j]<=x && x<V[j+1]) f0=j/N;
            else if (x>=V[N-1])      f0=1;
            Z[i*N+j]=f0;
        }
    }
    return f0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: why doesnt it work? Does it not compile? Does it not perform as you wish? What is the difference from what the code does to what you want it to do?

Comment: when i make the plot it doesn't give the correct curve of empirical cdf
it gives all 0

Comment: (a) Use a debugger and (b) Integer division is probably not what you want here `f0=j/N`

Comment: Richard, but this is the definition of an empirical cdf .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is unclear why you need `N`, `Ndft` and `X.length()`. Aren't one value to be enough?
2. As mentioned by someone, in integer division `j/N` you're getting zeroes. Please make it to be `double(j)/double(N)`